# How to demarshal root-as-list xml with Jackson?

Tags: java, xml, jackson

I have some "root-as-list" XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rows code="0">
    <row number="0">
        <Reason_ID>1000055</Reason_ID>
        <Reason_name>Недостаточно средств</Reason_name>
        <Reason_externalId>DEB_LOCK</Reason_externalId>
    </row>
    <row number="1">
        <Reason_ID>2309864</Reason_ID>
        <Reason_name>Добровольная блокировка</Reason_name>
        <Reason_externalId>FREE_LOCK</Reason_externalId>
    </row>
    <row number="2">
        <Reason_ID>2310003</Reason_ID>
        <Reason_name>Технологическая блокировка</Reason_name>
        <Reason_externalId>TECH_LOCK</Reason_externalId>
    </row>
</rows>
```

How can i demarshall it to POJO? My wrong code:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "rows")
public class GetReasonsSdpResponse extends ABaseProtocolResponse {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7394464025399057638L;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "code", isAttribute = true)
    private int code;

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "row", useWrapping = false)
    private List<ReasonPart> rows = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Result:`GetReasonsSdpResponse{code=0, rows=[]}`

PS: Sorry for my poor English, please talk simply :)

Comment: Well im using this hack temporarily:  `private static final Pattern rowSelectorPattern = Pattern.compile("(<((row)|(service))[ >].*</\\2>)", Pattern.DOTALL);`  ... `rowSelectorPattern.matcher(result).replaceAll("<list>$1</list>")` ... and using  `private Row[] list`

Answer (score -2):

What is the reason you are using: 
    useWrapping = false

In the [Jackson XML annotations](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/wiki/Jackson-XML-annotations) documentation it seems to say that

> useWrapping (default:true) Whether to use wrapper element or not: by specifying 'false' one can disable use

So I would expect to not specify useWrapping = false if you want to include it on your unmarshalling.

Comment: Its a wrong experimental code. W/o this option not working too.

Comment: this is not an answer. this is actually a question or at best, a comment.